# How do I transfer my paxful bitcoin to litecoin and do I need a litecoin address

Tags: exchanges

How do I transfer my bitcoin to litecoin?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin and Litecoin are two separate currencies, so you can't just transfer a value from one to the other.

What you are looking for is someone who will accept your bitcoin as a means of purchasing litecoin.  This is what exchanges are for.  And yes, once you have purchased litecoin, you will need to store it in a wallet, and will therefore have many litecoin addresses.